# Question drafts

Tags: feature-request, questions, draft

I was working with a colleague on a particularly difficult problem one morning.  I realized it would be a decent question for Stack Overflow and began formulating the question on the Android app over lunch.  However, I didn't want to post it without marking it up on the computer. Then, I got stuck because all I could do was "Post" or "Discard".  What I really wanted to do was "Save".

Ultimately, I just started over. Could I have done anything differently (other than copied my text to dropbox)?  If not, could we add a feature to save drafts in our profile?

Comment: Stack Overflow automatically saves a draft every so often. The discard button discards the saved draft. The draft is saved for a period of time. It is possible to trigger this action by invoking the function call which saves the question as a draft.

Comment: So you wanted to "save" the question in the Android app, and have the saved text come up when opening the Stack Overflow web site on your computer?

Comment: @legoscia yes, that's the theory of operation I envisioned.  Or visa versa.  And it doesn't have to be like an inbox.  Just one draft saved in my profile somewhere.

Comment: @TinyGiant I've seen the draft saving in the event of loss of data, but it doesn't address closing/switching the browsers. Also, the draft actually causes more bad than good behind my company's firewall; if it saves a draft or two, it usually gives me the "There was an error posting".  Then I copy/reload/paste and it asks "Are you a robot?"...

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit more functionality than Stack Overflow is going to implement any time soon. My suggestion would be to write your questions up in a text editor, or a markdown editor, and save it to a cloud somewhere.

Comment: @TinyGiant That's a good enough answer for me.  Thanks.  _Back to Google Keep it is_

Comment: @reasra apparently I was wrong and this is saved server side (even though it didn't work when I tested it last night) so if it isn't working then it is probably either a bug or interference by your company's firewall.

Comment: You can always draft your question in a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/) which also supports Markdown formatting.

Comment: Not 100% on the repercussions of this (depends on rep, post might end up in a queue), but you could probably post and instantly delete? Then at your own leisure, edit and reopen. This might affect visibility of your question

Answer (score 6):

Drafts are saved automatically. If you just leave the page, then "Ask Question", you'll find what you typed should still be there.

You can also copy the text and save it to a text file. So I'm not sure why this needs to be a site feature.

Comment: "other than copied my text to dropbox".  I could agree.  And if the general consensus is "it's more trouble than it's worth", I get it.  This is simply a request.

Comment: I don't know why this answer is getting downvoted. It is exactly what I would have posted after reading the question. *"Then, I got stuck because all I could do was "Post" or "Discard". What I really wanted to do was "Save"."* That's because "Save" is the default option, and happens without you having to click anything. We don't need a new feature, because this feature already exists!

Comment: @cody it doesn't save across browsers, which is the situation described in the question and comments

Comment: I don't see that description anywhere in the question, @tiny. But you're right; I didn't read the comments.

Comment: @TinyGiant *it doesn't save across browsers,* [yes it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtmFf.png). The draft is saved server side. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: @rene interestingly when I tried that last night it didn't work. Weird.

Comment: @TinyGiant try harder next time ...

Comment: I haven't voted on anything yet. This is not a bad answer, but sadly, I apparently cannot utilize. I actually found stackedit.com where I can save to Dropbox. But I thought it vain to answer my own question.